# What do you call a student who always need to volunteer an answer to show off how smart they are?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I friend of mine, when teachers address questions to the whole class, always need to volunteer an answer to show off how smart they are.

Therefore, I'm looking for a term which define that my friend.

A bit of googling come up with 'suck', but Merriam-Webster doesn't have an entry which matches that description, being the best 'to act in an obsequious manner'.

So, what do you call a person like that student?

Comment: The answer depends on the source of his need. For example he could be bored and want the class to go faster. He could be smart and want to help out the teacher with accurate answers.

Comment: It would also depend on whether he was trying to impress the teachers (sucking up to them) or his class (showing off to them). He could show off to both teachers and class, but he can't suck up to the class because he is trying to show he is better than they are.

Comment: Your question already has the best answer, "show off". It is both a verb and a noun and is a very common expression among kids, it's also much less offensive than "to suck up to" someone.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, then?

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo There are many other users who know much much more than I do, but I've never been afraid to attempt to answer a question if I think I know the answer. Am I a show off, then? Perhaps everyone on ELU is, to one degree or another.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, don't worry, many persons  appear to function fine in the real-world despite showing deficits on the Web.

Comment: You know, some volunteer because they know the answers, and they enjoy participating in the class.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the person would just be called a *show off* or a *know it all*.  Neither have particularly good connotations; the first would definitely be derogatory in most settings.

Depending on the situation/person, *[insecure](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insecure)* could also fit the bill.

> Adjective
>
> insecure (comparative more insecure, superlative most insecure)
>
> 1. Not secure.
> 2. Not comfortable or confident in oneself or in certain situations.
>
> He's a nice guy and all, but seems to be rather insecure around other people.

Comment: +1 for [show-off:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show-off) *a person who tries to impress other people with his or her abilities or possessions.* If said jokingly to a friend, *show-off* wouldn't be that bad.

Comment: Neither one of those words really fits the specific situation.  Earnest may - although dated, and brown-noser is a good term too.

Answer (score 3):

Brown noser is a good overall term.  You can use **kiss-ass** too.  But in the US this specific example would be called a **teacher's pet**.

Comment: Not really.  A teacher's pet implies that there is some kind of favoritism shown by the teacher to the pupil.

Comment: Is 'kiss-ass' a derogatory term? My friend is a sensible person and I don't want to offend him.

Comment: If it is a friend then "teacher's pet" is a perfect phrase.  You can say, "Look at you answering all the questions.  You are a teacher's pet."   But to my good friends I would definitely say, "You are such a kiss-ass."  Yes it is derogatory but that is what friends are for.

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo: Yes, it's derogatory.  It could be used in a joking manner, but if you say it with serious intentions he probably won't appreciate it.

Comment: @Jacobm001 - in his question he asks how he would define his friend.  His friend is a kiss-ass.  He didn't say he would use that term to his friend.  Also in the US people would be more offended by suck up, brown noser, or show off.  Kiss-ass has more of a playful meaning than those terms.

Comment: I'd consider Kiss-ass, Brown Noser and Suck up all on the same level.  In my experience, Brown Noser is usually said with more humor, and Kiss-ass implies a bit of annoyance if not anger.  Really, suck-up seems the least possible to produce offense in my book...

West Coast (Oregon) perspective.

Comment: @Jacobm001 - I think kiss-ass isn't as bad here (midwest) because of its frequent use.  If you said the other words it is like you were thinking about it a while or going on SE asking people what to call someone.  Teacher's pet is a little dated too.  Not as bad as earnest but still dated.  Teacher's pet is definitely the nicest out of all of them - I don't count earnest because if you called someone that they would think you were calling them another name (Ernest) because that word just isn't used.

Comment: @RyeBread: That's alien to me.  While *ernest* isn't commonly used *ernestly* wouldn't be out of the ball park. **teacher's pet** has totally different connotations (as listed in m-w and wiktionary).

It seems like we would normally use *suck up* as you use *kiss ass*.

Answer (score 1):

know-it-all, but that's a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I hear the term *brown-noser* for that a lot.  The term you might have run across is *suck-up*.  I'd be careful with calling your friend "suck"  :)

Comment: If, as you mentioned in another comment, your friend is of a sensitive disposition, you should probably also not call him a brown-noser or a suck-up. Sucking up to someone has a very negative sound to it, and ‘brown-noser’ comes from the notion that if you ‘kiss ass’ (= suck up to someone), interpreted literally, then you will be positioning your nose in a way that … _brown stuff_ is likely to get on it. Both a slangy, negative, and also quite disgusting term, really.

Answer (score 0):

He's an **earnest** student...

> [**earnest**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/earnest) *- serious in intention, purpose, or effort; **sincerely zealous.***

Comment: I disagree with this one. An earnest student does not necessarily show off in class (he is just very serious and eager in _studying_), and a show-off like the one described in the question is not necessarily an earnest student (he might just be really clever by nature and not put much effort into studying).

Comment: I am not downvoting because I think it maybe could be used.  But if I called a friend earnest, they would think I was calling them by the first name Ernest.  "You answered a lot of questions today, you are very earnest".... "Huh?  My name is Jack."

Comment: @Janus: I know that strictly speaking, *earnest* is supposed to mean *serious, as opposed to trifling*. But in practice if you asked a teacher to say who was his most earnest student, I think they'd be influenced by *zealous* in my definition, and *eager* in yours - in short, they'd name the student who was most *keen* to show they were "actively engaged" in the classroom. It works for me, anyway, and at least it's not "slang", which all other offerings seem to be.

Comment: @RyeBread: [“There's no need to be so earnest, darling,”](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bRdQNQY3FaYC&pg=PA12&dq=%22need+to+be+so+earnest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Wj4zUqfeLNLY7Aa5o4C4Dw&ved=0CDYQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22need%20to%20be%20so%20earnest%22&f=false)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I know it's used but it is one of those words that is used in writing not forms of speech.  If I used it my friends might offer me a top hat or an outing chasing the foxes.

Comment: @RyeBread: Buy your friends dictionaries for Xmas!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You mean the dictionary app game right?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I agree that the teacher would probably say so. But this question is coming from the other students—and they tend to have a different look on these things. Plus, they tend to know whether someone is actually an earnest student, rather than just someone who can goof off and not do anything, but still be able to chirp up answers in class all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Pedantic or pedant - an ostentatious display of knowledge if it's of a factual or overly specific nature. Sententious if it has a moral or philosophical bent.

Answer (score 0):

[Conceited](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/conceited) - excessively proud of oneself; vain. (Oxford Dictionaries)

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/conceited "excessively proud of oneself; vain."

Comment: Thanks, I've edited your answer to include your source. Welcome to ELL!

Answer (score 0):

In a science context I'd use the phrase "*alpha-Geek*".